# change cursor property with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

i have coded a simple javascipt that when the user clicks sth, to do some stuff. I also want that the cursor to be changed, so i added this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {            
        $(".targetClass").click(function () {
            $('#loaderImage').show();
            //this is the line i add
            $('.container').css('cursor','wait');                
        });
    });
</script>
```

And it works. But if i take the cursor on a link the cursor will change again to "pointer" value. What i have to do so the cursor, after the click remain to wait value (even i put it on any element of the page)? Thx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element within the container will overwrite the cursor wait with it's default behaviour. You would have to set cursor wait to all elements.

```
$('*').css('cursor','wait');
```

You can use:

```
$('*').css('cursor','auto');
```

to set everything to default again.

Or possibly better:

```
$('*').css('cursor','');
```

to reset to the previous cursor state, therefore not overriding other cursor changes.

Answer (score 1):

**[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LDY3c/)** is the solution to your problem.

create a class with pointer wait and add it to button/link also while clicking on it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $(".targetClass").click(function () {
        //$('#loaderImage').show();
        //this is the line i add
        $('.container').css('cursor','wait');                
       $(this).addClass('cursor');
    });
});

  .cursor{

        cursor:wait;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just ADD this below CODE   [EXAMPLE HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepvirani/nYwYe/)**

(1) If all a links shows busy.

```
$('.container, a').css('cursor','wait');
```

(2) If all a links within CONTAINER shows busy.

```
$('.container, .container a').css('cursor','wait');
```

(3) If all a links within whole(DOM) page shows busy.

```
$('*').css('cursor','wait');
```

**[EXAMPLE HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepvirani/nYwYe/)**

Answer (score 0):

add the following to the function:

```
$(document).css('cursor','wait');
```